# Newbie issue with the onCreate method Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn some java code for android, and I'm stuck with this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form_layout);
}
```

As far as I'm concerned, @Override shows us that we're creating a method that is already contained in a superClass, which in this case should be Bundle, if the information I've read is correct. The problem is that when I look on the Android API, no 'onCreate' method appears in the Bundle section. If someone could help me I'd be so grateful, because I'm going crazy.

Comment: superClass is Activity

Comment: The method is defined inside `Activity` class, which you're subclassing. `Bundle` is the parameter type.

Comment: I'd suggest you start from basic Java/OOP tutorials first otherwise you will be doing things not understanding what it really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Override annotation` that is placed before the `onCreate()` method, means that you want to override the same `onCreate()` method that exists in it's super class. You didn't share us your entire code, but i'm assuming that your activity is extending either [Activity class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) or either [AppCompatActivity class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html).

```
MainActivity extends Activity {}
```

or

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {}
```

Regarding [Bundle class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html), i am assuming that you are reffering to `Bundle savedInstanceState`. If so, this means that you are using in your overriden method, `savedInstanceState` object which is of type `Bundle`, as an argument.

Regarding Bundles, that are generally used for passing data between various Android activities. It depends on you, what type of values you want to pass, but bundles can hold all types of values and pass them to the new activity.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That's incorrect.  @Override refers to the parent class, which is what comes after the extends keyword. i.e.

```
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {......}
```

Bundle, in this case, is the class type of the item being passed into the onCreate function.